# Confining colorful background to the area of an equation in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I would like to add a colorful background to equations. I have tried the code below, but, unfortunately, the colorful background expands to the margins instead of being confined to the equation. Could someone please help me?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

Some text

<div style="background-color: rgb(255,255,153);">
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_ 1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$$
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a CSS style.  Put this into your document, or in a separate CSS file included in the YAML header:

```
<style>
span.MathJax {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,153)
}
</style>
```

That will make all of your MathJax code have a yellow background.  If you only want display equations to have it, use

```
<style>
div.MathJax_Display > span.MathJax {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,153)
}
</style>
```

And if you only want one particular equation to have the colouring, then you should use a more specific selector, e.g.

```
<style>
#MathJax-Element-1-Frame {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,153)
}
</style>
```

where you would put in `#MathJax-Element-2-Frame` for the second equation, etc.  With lots of equations this could be tedious, so you could add a class to the ones you want to highlight and select those,
e.g.

```
<style>
div.Highlighted span.MathJax {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,153)
}
</style>

This one is regular:
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_ 1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$$

This one is highlighted:
<div class="Highlighted">
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_ 1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$$
</div>
```

According to the comments, Bookdown may need you to request HTML-CSS rendering, which can be done with the right mouse click on one of the equations, and following the menus to `Math Settings | Math Renderer | HTML-CSS`.

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330. In fact, I want to add a colorful background only to certain equations. BonzoFestoon's does not work, as the colorful background is put outside of the equation.

Comment: Added a couple of options for that.

Comment: Perfect answer, @user2554330! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Unfortunately, when I insert the code of your last window of code inside a chapter of a `bookdown::bs4_book`, it seems that the highlighted style is ignored. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, without more info (e.g. a reproducible example) I can't help.  You might try opening the .html page in a text editor and searching for the string `Highlighted`:  it's possible that name is being used by Bookdown, and you just need to choose another name.  Maybe if you post the whole block from `<div class="Highlighted">` to the ending `</div>` someone could spot the issue.

Comment: Good idea, @user2554330! Thanks!  `<style>
div.Highlighted span.MathJax {
  background-color: rgb(255,255,153)
}
</style>
<div class="Highlighted">
<p><span class="math display">\[Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.\]</span></p>
</div>`

Comment: Okay, it looks like you should use `div.Highlighted span.math` or maybe `div.Highlighted span.math.display` in place of the selector `div.Highlighted span.MathJax`.

Comment: Thanks, @user2554330. I have tried both ways and, while rendering the chapter, I can see the background of the equation turning yellow, but, as soon as the rendering process ends, the background becomes white again. Something is neutralizing `span.math`: A bug? That is a mystery!

Comment: The way MathJax works is to run some Javascript at display time that looks for things to replace with the nice typesetting.  You need to figure out what class it is putting in, and select that instead of the one that's in the file.  You can right click and Inspect to see the final stuff being displayed.

Comment: Fixed, now, @user2554330! The problem was caused by the fact that the deafult MathJax was not `HTML-CSS`. So, right-clicking on the equation and setting the renderer as `HTML-CSS` does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

A DIV is a block element by default.
A SPAN is an inline element.

Try this:

```
<span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,153);padding:10px;">
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_ 1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$$
</span>
```

The padding controls the amount of color around the equation.

Comment: Thanks, @BonzoFestoon, but it appears not being working: the colorful background is put outside the equation.

Comment: @PaulSmith Outside how? Do you mean the padding? The MD should be rendered to HTML something like this for the browser: https://jsfiddle.net/otumaegL/

Comment: Please, see: https://postimg.cc/4mDYf3GS

Comment: I believe the problem is not related with your code, but with some `rmarkdown` conflict, @BonzoFestoon. Thanks!